# DKIM aligned but not authenticated on On-Premises Exchange 2019

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, dkim

I have an On-Premises Exchange 2019 server with Hybrid Deployment with Office365 configured. Everything is working as expected, but DKIM aligned messages are arriving as unauthenticated.

I can confirm that the sender have properly authenticated DKIM, since other public mail providers receive the message correctly with proper DKIM alignment and authentication.

I've made the analysis with the MxToolbox Header Analysis tool, available [here](https://mxtoolbox.com/Public/Tools/EmailHeaders.aspx?huid=a8d6b6db-4d53-4635-9149-73e19b21e4c0).

Basically MxToolbox complains about a failed "DKIM Signature Body Hash Verified". I'm guessing this verification is made server side, on my On-Premises Exchanges, but I'm not sure.

So the whole point here is how to make my On-Premises server properly authenticate the messages it's receiving?

Answer (score 1):

Have you modified something before this issue occurs?

I have found an article on [On-Premises Exchange: DKIM and DMARC setup](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35595.on-premises-exchange-dkim-and-dmarc-setup.aspx) and you could refer to this article to check the steps you configured.

In addition, you could refer to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/use-dkim-to-validate-outbound-email?view=o365-worldwide) and it may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever get this resolved.  I'm seeing the same thing for mailboxes moved to our tenant, they have this in their header:

arc=fail (body hash mismatch);

SPF/DKIM/DMARC all pass using the records published in our own DNS.  We are in a hybrid config with only a handful of mailboxes in EXO currently.  Issue doesn't happen if you move it back to on prem.  Inbound/outbound email goes thru on prem still using a centralized mail transport for the EXO config.

Comment: Unfortunately not, and with the deprecation of Exchange 2022 and the uncertain of the on-premises server, we've moved everything to Microsoft365 (old Office365).

Comment: That's too bad.  We'll see what support says but not hopeful.

Comment: Report back what the support says to you, if you can.